# FubuMVC and OpenRasta documentation and resource

Tags: openrasta, fubumvc

im looking at using FuBuMVC or OpenRasta frameworks for the up coming projects we have here. Without getting into much details on the nature of the project I would like some opinions on the documentation, support, tutorials, communities behind the frameworks that are currently available. Which framework is more mature, are they production ready,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of featureset, openrasta is more focused on resource-oriented architectures, fubu provides more in terms of html integration.

Fubu is on their way to 1.0, we're closing in on 2.1.

Comment: just curious what is the most matured view engine for openrasta? can you provide a starting point for them? thanks

Comment: we have extensive support for webforms, including html helpers and API and a compiler rewriter. I personally won't be spending much more time on this, and invest my time supporting razor and spark going forward. As usual, work gets done based on requests and users and, hopefully, contributors :)

Answer (score 1):

Supporting documentation for OpenRasta can be found on the GitHub Wiki with some samples.

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki